# Why can't I override inherited function?

Tags: c++

When I tried to compile next construction I have got the error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'float'
Why dose it happen?

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual int action(float)
    {return 5;}

    virtual int action(std::vector<float>)
    {return 10;}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int action(float) override
    {return 6;}
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    int action(std::vector<float>) override
    {
       B::action(std::vector<float>());
       return 7;
    }
};

int main()
{
   C instance;
   int temp = instance.action(std::vector<float>());
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `B::action` does not accept a `std::vector<float>`, it merely accepts a `float` value. So clearly it cannot be called with a `std::vector<float>()` as an arg as you attempt to do in `C::action`

Comment: Actually, I thought that it should call action(std::vector<float>)inherited from  class A, but I can't find out why it doesn't happen.

Comment: It'ds an instance of the C class. C may inherit A and B but the way you override it here causes the program to remain local in scope and urges it to use the `action()` from the one enclosed in C's brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler sees a function call

```
B::action(std::vector<float>());
```

It needs two steps to decide which function call needs to be made. In the first step it looks up the name `action`. If the lookup results in one or more functions, it stops the lookup. It does not lookup the overloaded functions in base classes. If the lookup results in multiple function names, it tries overload resolution.

In your case, the lookup results in only one function - `int B::action(float)`. The lookup stops there. However, that function does not match the argument being used. Hence, the compiler reports it as an error.

I can think of the following ways to resolve the problem.

**Make all overloads of `A::action` available for lookup in `B`**

```
class B : public A
{
   public:
      using A::action;
      int action(float) override
      {return 6;}
};
```

**Change the call so it uses `A::action(float)`**

```
class C : public B
{
   public:
      int action(std::vector<float>) override
      {
         A::action(std::vector<float>());
         return 7;
      }
};
```

I strongly recommend using the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does *not* search for overloads in parent classes if the derived class declares a function by the same name. Typically, if you've enabled warnings, the compiler would warn something like:

> warning: 'C::action' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]

If you specify the scope where the overload is declared, the call will work:

```
A::action(std::vector<float>());
```

But more generally, you should always avoid overloading virtual functions.

Comment: What if have a long chain from let's say 8 classes (class A, B, ..., G, H), where function action(...) is implemented in class A, but now I need to override it in class H. Seems like using A::action(...) is not, good enough for this case, because someone can override it in class B, and forget to change from A::action(...) to B::action(...). Is there any way to use __super::action(...) or G::action(...)?

Comment: @OleksandrV You should probably avoid overloading virtual functions. Give each function a unique name.